# Bcrypt not hashing

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I'm trying to learn some Express.js, now I have some form sent from a React front end to my express server, and I'm inserting this data into a MongoDB schema. Following some online tutorials I've tried to hash the pin code inserted (this is not a system ever to reach production btw) using bcrypt, but data is always saved plainly, no encryption is made, using console log I also see that the pin code is not hashed.

My code for hashing resides in my mongoDB model, here is the model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Creates the needed schema
let userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date,
  balance: Number,
  address: String,
  ssn: Number,
  bankNumber: Number,
  cards: [
    {
      formType: String, // Visa eller Mastercard
      cardNumber: Number,
      cvc: Number,
      expirationDate: Date,
      pin: Number,
      status: Boolean,
    }
  ],
  whitdrawal: [
    {
      amount: Number,
      date: Date, 
      reason: String
    }
  ]
});
// Inserts
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  // 10 defines salt rounds
  let pin = this.cards[0].pin
  bcrypt.hash(pin, 10, function(err,hash){
    if(err){
      return next(err); 
    }
    pin = hash; 
  })
  this.updated_at = currentDate;
  this.date = currentDate;
  this.pin = pin; 
  console.log("Pin is " + pin)
  if (!this.created_at) this.created_at = currentDate;
  next();
});

// Creates model for schema
const AtmUser = mongoose.model('AtmUser', userSchema);

// Export so it is available for the rest of the application
module.exports = AtmUser;
```

It saves data to the schema just fine, it just does not encrypt the pin. Setting date from server in userSchema.pre works.

I'd be happy to post any additional code.

Comment: `bcrypt.hash(pin, 10, function(err,hash){` ... looks **asynchronous** - put everything from `this.updated_at = currentDate;` to the end of the function inside the callback

Comment: or don't supply a callback it seems, and it will return synchronously - read documentation to learn more https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Comment: I may be terribly off, but I've tried something like this earlier and it crashed my app
code. https://dpaste.de/PHyK
error log: https://dpaste.de/XX02

Comment: its an async operation, async the function and await the crypt, should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `bcrypt.hash(..., function(err, hash) { ... })` calls back the supplied callback **asyncrhonously**

therefore

```
this.updated_at = currentDate;
this.date = currentDate;
this.pin = pin; 
console.log("Pin is " + pin)
// etc
```

Will execute before

```
pin = hash;
```

has a chance to run.

There are three options

Using callbacks properly, put ALL the code that relies on the `hash` inside the callback

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    // 10 defines salt rounds
    let pin = this.cards[0].pin;
    bcrypt.hash(pin, 10, (err, pin) => {
        if (!err) {
            this.updated_at = currentDate;
            this.date = currentDate;
            this.pin = pin; 
            console.log("Pin is " + pin)
            if (!this.created_at) this.created_at = currentDate;
        }
        next(err);
    })
});
```

the above without arrow functions (but you use `let` in your code, so you should know arrow function, I hope - just in case)

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    // 10 defines salt rounds
    let pin = this.cards[0].pin;
    let _this = this; // save _this for the callback
    bcrypt.hash(pin, 10, function(err, pin) {
        if (!err) {
            _this.updated_at = currentDate;
            _this.date = currentDate;
            _this.pin = pin; 
            console.log("Pin is " + pin)
            if (!_this.created_at) _this.created_at = currentDate;
        }
        next(err);
    })
});
```

or, using Promises

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    // 10 defines salt rounds
    let pin = this.cards[0].pin
    bcrypt.hash(pin, 10).then((pin) => {
        this.updated_at = currentDate;
        this.date = currentDate;
        this.pin = pin; 
        console.log("Pin is " + pin)
        if (!this.created_at) this.created_at = currentDate;
        next();
    }).catch((err) => {
        next(err); 
    })
});
```

and finally, using async/await

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    // 10 defines salt rounds
    let pin = this.cards[0].pin
    try {
        pin = await bcrypt.hash(pin, 10);
    } catch(err) {
        return next(err); 
    }
    this.updated_at = currentDate;
    this.date = currentDate;
    this.pin = pin; 
    console.log("Pin is " + pin)
    if (!this.created_at) this.created_at = currentDate;
    next();
});
```

There is a fourth option, but there's never a good reason to `.hash` synchronously

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed answer, reading up on async/await now. I tried all your three supplied methods but they all return the same error. 
error https://dpaste.de/EAGo
full code (using your method 1) https://dpaste.de/QcjR

Comment: sorry, let me fix that ... I should be using arrow notation in the first two code blocks

Comment: I hope you understand `arrow functions` @sam_vimes

Comment: @sam_vimes - I've added a "non-arrow-function" version of the callback code

Comment: I have not yet begun on ES6, but I've used them a bit so I understand the basics of them, I intend to use them later on in this app. 
Your revised code still produces the same error, even with the arrow functions. By "Data must be a string" I assume node is talking about "pin" variable, I tried adding "pin = hash" to your code as per the medium post posted on the bottom, but the error still persists
https://medium.com/createdd-notes/starting-with-authentication-a-tutorial-with-node-js-and-mongodb-25d524ca0359

Comment: actually, having the `pin = hash` in the code (which I've now removed) is wrong - since the `pin` argument to the callback function should be the hashed pin

Comment: oh I figured so, it was just my attemt, any ideas of why I'm still getting the error? (now removed pin = hash). I tested your latest revision of the code

Comment: Is the hashed pin a string? Don't trust log, it coerces to string. Try logging typeof pin

Comment: Thank you Jaromanda X, typeof helped me spot the issue. You have provided excellent help, now I need to read some arrow function tutorials. My program now works as expected